# Correction term in the relation between the Itō and Stratonovich integrals in Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-calculus, operator-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm reading the paper [On the relation between the Itō and Stratonovich integrals in Hilbert spaces](http://www.sbc.org.pl/Content/33707/2004_04.pdf) and there is something I don't understand.

In the notation of the paper, let

- $H,H_1$ be separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $Q\in\mathfrak L(H)$ be nonnegative and self-adjoint with finite trace
- $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ with $$Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq(0,\infty)$
- $B:H_1\to\mathfrak L(H,H_1)$

> They show (and that is easy to see) that for any $y\in H_1$ and $L\in\mathfrak L(H,\mathfrak L(H,H_1))$, there is a unique $\tilde L(y)\in\mathfrak L(U)$ with $$\langle y,(Lu)v\rangle_H=\langle v,\tilde L(y)u\rangle_U\;\;\;\text{for all }u,v\in H\tag 1$$ and a unique $\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:QL\in H_1$ with $$\operatorname{tr}Q\tilde L(y)=\langle y,\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:QL\rangle_H\;\;\;\text{for all }y\tag 2$$ given by $$\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:QL=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(Le_n)(\lambda_ne_n)\;.\tag 3$$

In particular, $$\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:Q{\rm D}B(x)B(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}({\rm D}B(x)B(x)e_n)(\lambda_ne_n)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H_1\;.\tag 4$$

In the paper, they consider a SDE $${\rm d}z_t=[Az_t+C(z_t)]{\rm d}t+B(z_t){\rm d}W_t$$ where only the operator $C$ on $H_1$ is of (marginal) interest in the following. They state the following assumptions:

> (A3): $\exists K>0$ with $$\left\|C(x)\right\|_{H_1}^2+\operatorname{tr}B(x)Q{B(x)}^\ast\le K(1+\left\|x\right\|_{H_1}^2)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H_1\tag 5$$ and $$\left\|C(x)-C(y)\right\|_{H_1}^2+\operatorname{tr}(B(x)-B(y))Q(B(x)-B(y))^\ast\le K\left\|x-y\right\|_{H_1}^2\tag 6\;.$$
>
> (A4): $B$ is continuously Fréchet differentiable with bounded, Lipschitz-continuous derivative.

**Question**: Now they state that (A4) and the convergence of the series in $(4)$ would imply (A3). *Why*? I absolutely don't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase what you said, the paper you cite introduces an Ito SDE in (2.3) and a second Ito SDE in (2.4), which has an Ito-Stratonovich correction term.  The paper then states that assumptions (A1)-(A4) imply existence and uniqueness of a mild solution for *both* (2.3) and (2.4).  They claim that the latter statement follows from the fact that the Ito-Stratonovich correction term appearing in the drift of (2.4) satisfies their (restrictive) assumptions on the infinite-dimensional drift given in (A3).

This latter conclusion sounds fishy at first glance, because the Ito-Stratonovich correction term does not appear to be globally Lipschitz (i.e., satisfies (A3)).  To see what the issue is, suppose $B$ was in $C^2$, then the Frechet derivative of the correction term involves $B$ itself, which is not necessarily bounded by their assumptions.  In much simpler terms, if a $C^2$ function $f$ has bounded first derivative then $f'(x) f(x)$ (the correction term) does not always have bounded first derivative; take for instance $f(x) = x + \cos(x)$.  However, I think their point is that even though the term $D^2B(x) B(x)$ is not necessarily bounded, its convolution with $Q$ as defined by that series is bounded.

Comment: Did you mean ${\rm D}B(x)B(x)$ instead of ${\rm D}^2B(x)B(x)$ in your last sentence? They don't talk about the second Fréchet derivative of $B$ in the paper.

Comment: If I got you right, you think that they mean that, instead of $(5)$ and $(6)$, $$\left\|C(x)\right\|_{H_1}^2+\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:Q{\rm D}B(x)B(x)\le K(1+\left\|x\right\|_{H_1}^2)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H_1\tag{5'}$$ and $$\left\|C(x)-C(y)\right\|_{H_1}^2+\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:Q({\rm D}B(x)-{\rm D}B(y))(B(x)-B(y))\le K\left\|x-y\right\|_{H_1}^2\tag{6'}$$ are satisfied, right? If that's the case, could you write down how exactly $(5')$ and $(6')$ follow from (A4) and the convergence of the series in $(4)$?

Comment: I've made a typo. I've intended to write down $$\left\|C(x)\right\|_{H_1}^2+\left\|\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:Q{\rm D}B(x)B(x)\right\|_{H_1}\le K(1+\left\|x\right\|_{H_1}^2)\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in H_1\tag{5''}$$ and $$\left\|C(x)-C(y)\right\|_{H_1}^2+\left\|\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:Q({\rm D}B(x)-{\rm D}B(y))(B(x)-B(y))\right\|_{H_1}\le K\left\|x-y\right\|_{H_1}^2\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in H_1\tag{6''}\;.$$

Comment: You didn't respond the crucial part of my question. Do you think that they mean that $(5'')$ and $(6'')$ are satisfied, instead of $(5)$ and $(6)$? And do you think we can achieve a similar result for the trace term in the Itō formula? I've asked [another question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248203/properties-of-the-trace-term-in-the-it%c5%8d-formula) for that and hope you can help there too.

Comment: No. They do not mean (5'') and (6''). They mean that the *corrected* nonlinear part of the drift still satisfies (A3).  To be sure, if we label the correction term as $C_1(x)$, they mean: $\| C_1(x) \|_{H_1}^2 \le K (1+ \|x\|_{H_1}^2)$ (linear growth condition) and $\| C_1(x) - C_1(y) \|_{H_1}^2 \le K \| x - y \|_{H_1}^2$ (globally Lipschitz).  With the caveat given in my answer, the proof of this result seems math.stackexchange level.

Comment: Indeed, since the convolution defining the correction term is bounded and $C^1$, it is straightforward to prove that it is globally Lipschitz.  Moreover, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227314/relation-between-lipschitz-condition-and-linear-growth-condition

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "corrected nonlinear part of the drift", but I guess $$C_1(x)=C(x)+\frac12\tilde{\operatorname{tr}}\:Q{\rm D}B(x)B(x)\;,$$ right?

Comment: Of course. I didn't accept it so far, cause I wanted to make sure that I've understood what you've written. Let me ask you a last question on the paper: They write that $w$ is a $Q$-Wiener process, but from the series representation on page 2 it seems like $w$ is a cylindrical Wiener process (cause otherwise the square-roots $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ of the eigenvalues of $Q$ should occur in that series). Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: They really mean that $w$ is a $Q$-Wiener process: please note that the left-hand-side of (2.1) involves the eigenvalues of $Q$.   I think (2.4) is right, since the role of this term is to eliminate the Ito correction to the standard chain rule -- that is the essence of the Stratonovich description.

Comment: (a) But then the series representation above (2.1) is wrong, isn't it? (b) The remaining question is: *How* restrictive is the assumption (A3) for the drift of (2.3)? With part (b) of my last two comments in the other question in mind, the reason why I'm asking this question is cause I'm thinking about interpreting equation $(1)$ in the other question in the Stratonovich sense. If I'm doing that, I don't need to deal with the (bad?) trace term in the SDE for $u$ which comes from the application of the Itō formula.

Comment: However, cause I want to use well-known existence theory for solutions as, for example, presented in [Da Prato's book](http://tinyurl.com/hncprcn) (Google books link), I would need to convert my equation into the corresponding Itō equation. The result of the paper discussed here is exactly what I want, but now I'm unsure whether or not the drift of my equation will satisfy (A3) or not.

Comment: I think that the discussion here is complete. However, I still got a question related to your last comment and asked a [new question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248471/existence-of-a-solution-to-an-infinite-dimensional-stratonovich-sde).