# Existence of a solution to an infinite dimensional Stratonovich SDE

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, operator-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $U,H$ be separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $Q\in\mathfrak L(U)$ be nonnegative and self-adjoint with finite trace
- $U_0:=Q^{1/2}U$
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0},\operatorname P)$ be a filtered probability space
- $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a $Q$-Wiener process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0},\operatorname P)$
- $u\in C^{1,\:2}([0,\infty)\times H,H)$
- $G:[0,\infty)\times H\to\operatorname{HS}(U_0,H)$ with $G(t,\;\cdot\;)$ being Fréchet differentiable for all $t\ge 0$
- $X_0$ be a $\mathcal F_0$-measurable random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ and $$X_t:=X_0+\int_0^tu(s,X_s)\:{\rm d}s+\int_0^tG(s,X_s)\circ{\rm d}W_s\;\;\;\text{for }t>0\tag 1$$

By definition of $X$, we obtain $${\rm d}u(t,X_t)=\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,X_t)+{\rm D}u(t,X_t)u(t,X_t)\right]{\rm d}t+\underbrace{{\rm D}u(t,X_t)G(t,X_t)}_{=:\:\Phi(t,X_t)}\circ{\rm d}W_t\tag 2$$ for all $t\ge 0$. If we interpret $t\mapsto X_t$ as being the trajectory of a fluid particle perturbed in the sense of $(1)$ and $u(t,X_t)$ as being the velocity of this particle at time $t$, then it's not far from being reasonable to assume $${\rm d}u(t,X_t)=\left[-\frac1\rho\nabla p(t,X_t)+\nu\Delta u(t,X_t)\right]{\rm d}t\tag 3$$ for all $t\ge 0$ by *conservation of momentum* for some $\rho,\mu>0$ and $p:[0,\infty)\times H\to\mathbb R$ with $p(t,\;\cdot\;)\in C^1(\Lambda)$ for all $t\ge 0$ for some bounded and open $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ for all $t\ge 0$ in the case $H=\mathbb R^d$ for some $d\in\mathbb N$. By equating $(2)$ and $(3)$, we obtain a SDE for $u$. Actually, I want to solve that SDE numerically. However, I want to ensure that a solution (in some suitable sense) is guaranteed by well-known theory (e.g. the [results presented by Da Prato](https://books.google.de/books?id=bxkmAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=%22To+cover+this+important+case+we+will+introduce+the+following+assumptions%22&source=bl&ots=-3foObTT8x&sig=F7scdbxmheJDYyahqELSYcvnGP0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0jsrApeLOAhUGUBQKHX1nDecQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22To%20cover%20this%20important%20case%20we%20will%20introduce%20the%20following%20assumptions%22&f=false)). $(2)$ is understood in the Stratonovich sense. Since I'm not aware of any textbook which establishes existence theory for Stratonovich SDEs, I suppose that we need to convert $(2)$ into its equivalent Itō equation $${\rm d}u(t,X_t)=\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,X_t)+\underbrace{{\rm D}u(t,X_t)u(t,X_t)}_{=:\:C_1(t,X_t)}+\frac12\underbrace{\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt{\lambda_n}\left({\rm D}\Phi(t,X_t)\left(\Phi(t,X_t)e_n\right)\right)e_n}_{=:\:C_2(t,X_t)}\right]{\rm d}t+\Phi(t,X_t){\rm d}W_t\tag 4$$ for all $t\ge 0$, where $(e_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis of $U$ with $$Qe_n=\lambda_ne_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 5$$ for some $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$.

> My problem is that I'm unsure whether the nonlinear part of the drift in $(4)$ satisfies the usual growth and Lipschitz conditions as, for example, [presented in Da Prato's book in (7.25) and (7.26)](https://books.google.de/books?id=bxkmAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=%22To+cover+this+important+case+we+will+introduce+the+following+assumptions%22&source=bl&ots=-3foObTT8x&sig=F7scdbxmheJDYyahqELSYcvnGP0&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0jsrApeLOAhUGUBQKHX1nDecQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=%22To%20cover%20this%20important%20case%20we%20will%20introduce%20the%20following%20assumptions%22&f=false). Namely: $$\left\|C(t,x)-C(t,y)\right\|_H\le K\left\|x-y\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\text{ and }x,y\in H\tag 6$$ and $$\left\|C(t,x)\right\|_H\le K(1+\left\|x\right\|_H)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\text{ and }x\in H\tag 7$$ for some $K>0$, where $C:=C_1+\frac12C_2$. So, the question is: Does the drift satisfy these assumptions such that we can use the results presented in the book? And if not, can the existence of a solution be obtained in another way?

Comment: Can you please remove Stranonovich's circle from the last term in (4)?

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Why did you delete your answers of this and the [other question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/248203/properties-of-the-trace-term-in-the-it%c5%8d-formula)? I wasn't able to work at these problems for the last couple of days and just wanted to face them again. I'm sorry if it takes long, but I cannot accept an answer before I understood it. Could you please undelete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for (2) to hold, it seems that Ito's formula needs to hold for the stochastic process $X(s)$, $0 \le s \le t$.  This already requires that: (i) this process is well-defined; and (b) the Frechet partial derivatives $\partial_t u$, $\partial_x u$, and $\partial_{xx} u$ are continuous and locally bounded.  To check that (1) is well-defined, please write it in Ito form - which is doable since $W$ is a $Q$-Wiener process.  The Ito form of (1) is then: 
$$
dX_t = \underbrace{\left(u(t,X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sqrt{\lambda_n} ( \partial_x G(t,X_t) (G(t,X_t) e_n)) e_n\right)}_{=\tilde u(t,X_t)}  dt + G(t,X_t) dW_t 
$$
If one insists on using existence/uniqueness theory based on Lipschitz nonlinearities, then one has to check that $\tilde u(t,x)$ is globally Lipschitz.  One can do this by verifying that its Frechet partial derivative $\partial_x \tilde u(t,x)$ is bounded uniformly in $x$ for any $t$.  To obtain this bound it suffices that: for any $t>0$ and for all $x \in H$, there exists a real constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\max\left\{ \| \partial_x u(t,x) \|_H,  \| \partial_{xx} G(t,x) \|, \| \partial_x G(t,x) \|, \| G(t,x) \|  \right\} \le C \;.
$$ The linear growth condition follows immediately from this assumption. One can analogously obtain sufficient conditions for (4).

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. Let's be rigorous: (1) You say that $∂u/∂t$, ${\rm D}u$ and ${\rm D}^2u$ need to be continuous and locally bounded. By definition of $u$, that's the case (and note that a continuous function between normed vector spaces is always locally bounded). I guess you think that we need that in order to apply the Itō formula. However, in the [formulation of the Itō formula that I know (Google Books link)](http://tinyurl.com/hcfbvd8), we need that $∂u/∂t$, ${\rm D}u$ and ${\rm D}^2u$ are uniformly continuous on bounded subsets of $[0,T]\times H$. In the scenario of

Comment: the question, $u$ should actually be a mapping $[0,T]\times\overlineλ\to\mathbb R^d$ for some $T>0$ and a bounded and open $λ\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ (let's assume that from now on). So, since $∂u/∂t$, ${\rm D}u$ and ${\rm D}^2u$ are continuous and $\overlineλ$ is compact, the former property is satisfied too. (2) You say that its possible to write $(1)$ in an equivalent Itō form, since $W$ is a $Q$-Wiener process. Maybe you can explain why you think that it's important that $W$ is a $Q$-Wiener process. I think that it should work in the case of a cylindrical Wiener process (which is nothing else

Comment: than a $ιι^*$-Wiener process on another separable Hilbert space $V$ with a Hilbert-Schmidt embedding $ι$ from $U_0$ to $V$) too. (3) I think there is something wrong with your correction term. $G(t,x)$ is a mapping $U_0\to\mathbb R^d$, but your correction term involves an invocation of $G(t,x)$ with parameter $e_n$, which is in $U\supseteq U_0$. Maybe there is something I'm missing. That's likely to be the case, cause I've found the same correction term in a [book (Google Books link)](http://tinyurl.com/h5mxkhq). However, as I said, $G(t,x)e_n$ isn't defined and I think the correction term

Comment: should be $\frac12\tilde{\text{tr}}\:Q^{1/2}{\rm D}G(t,x)G(t,x)$ with $$\underbrace{\tilde{\text{tr}}\:Q^{1/2}{\rm D}G(t,x)G(t,x)}_{=:\:F(t,x)}:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt{λ_n}\left({\rm D}G(t,x)G(t,x)e_n^0\right)e_n^0$$ where $e_n^0:=\sqrt{λ_n}e_n$. $(4)$ Indeed, it's easy to see that $F(t,\;\cdot\;)$ is Lipschitz continuous for all $t\in[0,T]$. Together with the other mentioned properties of the coefficients, we obtain the existence of a mild (Itō-)solution (cf. [Theorem 7.2 in Da Prato's book (Google Books link](http://tinyurl.com/zvwxvz9)). However, we need a strong solution in order to

Comment: apply the Itō formula, don't we? What am I missing? $(5)$ In the context of the Navier-Stokes scenario described in the question: Do you know a suitable choice for $G$? [I know these are a lot of question. Thank you, once again, in advance for your effort].

Comment: (#2) Why is the SPDE (1) ill-posed in the case of a cylindrical Wiener process?  Note the Ito correction term involves the Frechet partial derivative of $G$, which is not bounded by our assumptions.  Thus, this infinite series will diverge unless the $\{ \lambda_n \}$ decay fast enough, or in other words, $W$ really needs to be a $Q$-Wiener process in order to avoid this divergence.

Comment: (#3) $G(t,x)$ is a linear operator that inputs  $u \in U_0$ and outputs $G(t,x) u \in H$, not quite $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Since an eigenfunction $e_n$ *trivially* belongs to $U_0$, $e_n$ is in the domain of the linear operator $G(t,x)$ and $G(t,x) e_n$ makes sense.  I am not sure what the purpose of rescaling $e_n$ by $\sqrt{\lambda_n}$?  Is the point to get $e_n$ to belong to $U_0$, but it already is...

Comment: (#4) Be careful: I don't quite see why $F(t,\cdot)$ is Lipschitz continuous without assuming that the first and second Frechet partial derivatives of $G$ are uniformly bounded.

Comment: (#5) I don't know a suitable choice for $G$.  This is a modeling question, which is outside my area of expertise.  BTW, I agree with everything you said in (#1), so I have nothing to add to that.

Comment: (4) You've got me wrong. What I've meant is that it's easy to se that $F(t,\;\cdot\;)$ is Lipschitz continuous, if we assume that the condition you've proposed in your answer is satisfied. (2) The Fréchet partial derivatives of $G$ *are* bounded by our assumption (again, assuming that your condition is satisfied). But besides that, I still don't understand why it would be a problem, if $W$ is a cylindrical Wiener process. As I said, a cylindrical Wiener process is just a $ιι^∗$-Wiener process on another separable Hilbert space $V$ with a Hilbert-Schmidt embedding $ι$ from $U_0$ to $V$ and the

Comment: eigenvalues of $ιι^∗$ *will* decay fast enough. Note that the correction term then will contain these eigenvalues (instead of the $\lambda_n$). $(3)$ The point is that the $e_n^0$ form an orthonormal basis of $U_0$. Moreover, the term $\tilde{\text{tr}}\:Q^{1/2}{\rm D}G(t,x)G(t,x)$ I've mentioned has the following property which is consistent with the paper we've discussed in the other question (I'm assuming $H=\mathbb R^d$, cause that's the proper choice for the Navier-Stokes scenario described in the question): Let $L:={\rm D}G(t,x)G(t,x)$ for some fixed $t\in[0,T]$ and $x\in\overline Λ$.

Comment: Fix $y\in\mathbb R^d$ and let $$L_y(u_0,v_0):=(Lu_0)v_0\cdot y\;\;\;\text{for }u_0,v_0\in U_0\;.$$ By Riesz' representation theorem, there is a unique $\tilde L_y\in\mathfrak L(U_0)$ with $$L_y(u_0,v_0)=\langle v_0,\tilde L_yu_0\rangle_{U_0}\;\;\;\text{for all }u_0,v_0\in U_0\;.$$ Now, $$\operatorname{tr}Q^{1/2}\tilde L_y=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt{\lambda_n}(Le_n^0)e_n^0\cdot y$$ and, since $y\mapsto\operatorname{tr}Q^{1/2}\tilde L_y$ is a bounded linear form, we obtain a unique element $\tilde{\text{tr}}\:Q^{1/2}{\rm D}G(t,x)G(t,x)\in\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^d)$ which is obviously given by my

Comment: definition in my former comment. Besides that: The crucial part of (4) was that the argumentation until now should only guarantee the existence of a mild solution, but we need a strong solution in order to apply the Itō formula. [Don't worry I will flag your comments as being helpful and accept and upvote your question as soon as I understood everything.]

Comment: (#2)  The Ito correction term is well-defined if we additionally assume that $L: U_0 \times U_0 \to H$ is a *bilinear Hilbert-Schmidt operator*.  (#3) An orthonormal basis for $U_0 = \{ Q^{1/2} x: x \in U \}$ is given by $\{ e_n \}$, because fractional powers of linear operators have the same eigenfunctions as the linear operator they are based on; cf. (5) above.  (#4) A mild solution suffices to use Ito's formula.

Comment: (3) $Q^{1/2}e_n=\sqrt{\lambda_n}e_n$, sure, but $U_0$ is equipped with a new inner product $$\langle u,v\rangle_{U_0}:=\langle Q^{-1/2}u,Q^{-1/2}v\rangle_U$$ such that the $e_n$ don't form an orthonormal set in $U_0$. (4) Do you've got a reference for that?

Comment: (#3) I agree, but then aren't our formulas for the correction term identical if you express things in terms of $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_U$? (#4) For a statement/proof of Ito formula for Hilbert space valued semimartingales see Theorem 27.2 in Part 2 of:  Metivier, Michel (1982).  Semimartingales: A Course on Stochastic Processes (Berlin, De Gruyer).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the study of general semimartingales. However, in light of [*A mild Itô formula for SPDEs*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.3526v4.pdf) by Giuseppe Da Prato, Arnulf Jentzen and Michael Röckner, I still doubt that formula $(2)$ (cf. $(3)$ in the referenced paper) really holds, unless $X$ is a *strong* solution of $(1)$. In fact, I think that, given that $X$ is only a *mild* solution of $(1)$, we only obtain a formula corresponding to $(5)$ in the referenced paper. Since this is crucial, I hope we can clarify it.

Comment: That paper treats a slightly harder SPDE problem than this case -- this case basically falls under special case discussed around (4) in that reference. Suggestion: *formally* apply Ito's formula to the scalar process: $F(t, X(t)) = \langle u(t, X(t)), \varphi \rangle_H $ where $\varphi \in H$ is a suitable test function.  To justify this formal calculation work with this weak form of the solution and retrace the steps given in Section 4.4 of: Da Prato, Giuseppe, and Jerzy Zabczyk. *Stochastic equations in infinite dimensions.* Cambridge university press, 2014.

Comment: The reason that reference cannot use the standard Ito formula is that  with cylindrical wiener process there are infinities in the correction to the usual chain rule in Ito formula.  In your case, which is analogous to (4), all of the terms are convergent.  By retracing the proof of Itos formula, you can justify this, but it's not a surprising result.

Comment: Actually, I want to consider a cylindrical $Q$-Wiener process with $Q=\text{id}_U$ in my real application. I just wanted to start with a normal $Q$-Wiener process and look what happens. But let's take one thing at a time: (a) I'm aware of the proof of the Itō formula presented in Da Prato's book, but I'm not sure what you exactly want me to do. You want that I formally apply the Itō formula with your $F$ and then justify this calculation **under the assumption that $X$ is a mild solution**, right? (b) Since I need $W$ to be a cylindrical ($Q$-)Wiener process (with $Q=\text{id}_U$) in my real

Comment: application, it's important for me that everything works in that case too. Let $V$ be another separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space with $U\subseteq V$ (in the sense of sets, i.e. $U$ and $V$ are equipped with different inner products) and such that the inclusion $\iota:U\to V$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. It's easy to see that $\tilde Q:=\iota\iota^\ast$ is a bounded, linear, nonnegative and self-adjoint operator on $V$. Moreover, if $\left\{B^{(n)}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is a family of independent $\mathcal F$-Brownian motions on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$, then

Comment: $\left(W_t^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $$W_t^{(n)}:=\sum_{i=1}^nB^{(i)}_t\iota e_i\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N$$ converges in $L^2(\operatorname P,V)$ to some $W_t$, for all $t\ge 0$, such that $(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$ is a ($V$-valued) $\tilde Q$-Wiener process on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathcal F,\operatorname P)$ (there are stronger convergence results available, if necessary). Now, if we interpret the stochastic integrals with respect to our new $W$, everything should work as before (note that $U_0=U$ and, most notably, $V_0:={\tilde Q}^{1/2}V=U$). Where do you see a problem?

Comment: *then justify this calculation under the assumption that X is a **weak** solution*  Yes.  This should be an easy exercise because your noise coefficient operator, the transformation and their derivatives are all HS by hypothesis.  Regarding your second point, I do not see a problem.

Comment: (a) I will think about that soon, but I just realized that I didn't thought about the actual shape of $(1)$. By the very definition, a mild solution of $(1)$ is also a strong solution, cause the drift of $(1)$ doesn't contain a linear part. So, it's clear that we can apply the (classical) Itō formula. Is there anything I'm missing? (b) If you don't see a problem, what exactly did you meant with "The reason that reference cannot use the standard Ito formula is that with cylindrical wiener process there are infinities in the correction to the usual chain rule in Ito formula"?

Comment: (a) Very good point about mild = strong in this case, but you can also justify the Ito chain rule with the weak solution.  It's a good exercise.   (b) Basically, their problem differs from this SPDE problem because they don't make the strong assumption that the derivatives of the transformation are HS operators.  Everything simplifies once you make this assumption, which is implicitly what you are doing when you pullback $W$ to $V$.

Comment: (a) I'm sorry, but I need to ask once again: Do you mean that the formula holds for a weak solution to a general SPDE as defined, for example, [here (Google Books link)](http://tinyurl.com/h6sz2u6) or do you mean that it holds for a weak solution to my specific SPDE $(1)$? The latter is trivial, cause a weak solution to $(1)$ is obviously a strong solution too.

Comment: Why is a weak solution for (1) a strong solution too?  (Its the other direction that is trivial.)  I mean that the formula holds for a weak solution to your specific SPDE (1), and to be crystal clear, it holds simply because all of the terms that appear in the formal application of Ito's rule are well-defined.  You constantly quote the trick about pulling back W to V, as if it solves the problem magically.  **There is no magic.**  Your operators have a very strong regularizing effect on the noise by assumption.

Comment: You just assume that the derivatives of all the functions occurring in the Itō form of $(1)$ are bounded and hence globally Lipschitz continuous with sublinear growth. I would agree that this yields the existence of a unique mild solution (which is, in fact, a strong solution in our special case). However, I've seen (e.g. [here](http://www.ros.hw.ac.uk/bitstream/handle/10399/2883/TzitziliE_1015_macs.pdf?sequence=1)(in Assumption 4.0.8) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1889)(in Assumption 2.3)) that many authors assume that even

Comment: $$\left\|{\rm D}_xG(t,x)G(t,x)-{\rm D}_xG(t,y)G(t,y)\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^{2}(U_0,\:H)}\le C\left\|x-y\right\|_H\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,T]\text{ and }x\in H\tag 8$$ for some $C\ge 0$, where $\operatorname{HS}^{2}(U_0,H)$ denotes the space of bilinear Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $U_0\times U_0$ to $H$. I'm not sure how restrictive this condition is, but it is at least less intuitive to me why this assumption is of any use at all. Do you have an idea why they assume it?

Comment: Let me note that without any further assumption (i.e. if we only know that $G(t,\;\cdot\;)\in C^1(H,\mathfrak L(U,H))$ for all $t\in[0,T]$), it's easy to see that $B(t,x)$, with $$B(t,x)(u_0,v_0):=({\rm D}_xG(t,x)(G(t,x)u_0))v_0\;\;\;\text{for }u_0,v_0\in U_0\;,$$ is in $\operatorname{HS}^{2}(U_0,H)$.

Comment: Nice references.  I'll take a look and get back to you asap.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the reason is that we need $$\left\|\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}B(t,x)(e_0^n,e_0^n)-\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}B(t,x)(e_0^n,e_0^n)\right\|_H\le C\left\|x-y\right\|_H$$ which is not much weaker than $$\left\|B(t,x)-B(t,y)\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^2(U_0,\:H)≤ C\left\|x-y\right\|_H\;.\tag 9$$ However, the additional sublinear growth assumption $$\left\|B(t,x)\right\|_{\operatorname{HS}^2(U_0,\:H)\le C(1+\left\|x\right\|_H)$$ is redundant, if we assume that $G$ and $\partial G$ have sublinear growth (in contrast, the Lipschitz continuity of $G$ and $\partial G$ is not sufficient for $(9)$).

Comment: The last question in this thread is not *that* important to me. I've [just asked a way more important question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256378/reformulation-of-a-spde-as-an-infinite-dimensional-sde) where I couldn't find a solution for a quite long time now. Maybe you can help there.